# iterating over a table of checkboxes with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table such as this coded in my asp.net mvc view:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>Option 1<td>
   <td>Option 2<td>
   <td>Option 3<td>
   <td>Option 4<td>
  <tr>
foreach(var options in Model)
 {
  <tr>
   <td>@Html.ChecBoxFor(x => x.one)<td>
   <td>@Html.ChecBoxFor(x => x.two)<td>
   <td>@Html.ChecBoxFor(x => x.three)<td>
   <td>@Html.ChecBoxFor(x => x.four)<td>
  <tr>
 }
<table>
```

I am trying to figure out how to iterate through each row and then conditionally toggle certain checkboxes. For example, if checkbox one is checked then make sure checkbox four is unchecked and vice versa.  The conditon would apply to checkboxes two and three respectively.

Comment: Something similar to what radio buttons already do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this in JSFiddle. Clich to see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WRQjQ/)

```
    $(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        $("tr").each(function() {
            var $RowCheckBoxes = $(this).find("input:checkbox");

            // if checkbox one is checked then make sure checkbox four is unchecked
            if ($RowCheckBoxes.eq(0).is(':checked') == true) {
                $RowCheckBoxes.eq(3).prop("checked", false);
            }

            // The conditon would apply to checkboxes two and three respectively.
            if ($RowCheckBoxes.eq(1).is(':checked') == true) {
                $RowCheckBoxes.eq(2).prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I made one change so that it would check on the fly. I changed $("btn").click to $("input:checkbox").change.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery for this basic task, just give yours checkboxes a name and:

```
var chk = document.getElementsByName("theName");
for(var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++){
  chk[i].whateverYouWant;
}
```